# Angularjs promise rejection chaining

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I need to create chained promises:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$timeout(function() {
    deferred.reject({result: 'errror'});
}, 3000);
deferred.promise.then(angular.noop, function errorHandler(result) {
    //some actions
    return result;
}).then(function successCallback(result) {
    console.log('what do I do here?');
    return result;
}, function errorCallback(result) {
   $scope.result= result;
   return result;
});
```

If I put an errorCallback into the first `then`, the second `then` will be resolved and its successCallback will be called . But if I remove `errorHandler` then second promise will be rejected.

According to Angular JS docs the only way to propagate rejection is to return `$q.reject();` and it looks not obvious, especially because I have to inject `$q` service even if it is not needed;

It can also be done by throwing an exception in `errorHandler`, but it writes exception trace to console, it is not good.

Is there another option to do this in a clear way? And what is the reason? Why it is done? In which case, the current behavior can be useful?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> And what the reason why it is done. In which case, the current behavior can be useful?

It can be useful when in errorHandler you could try to repair error state and resolve promise somehow.

```
var retriesCount = 0;

function doWork()
{
    return $http.post('url')
        .then(function(response){
            // check success-property of returned data
            if(response.data.success)
                // just unwrap data from response, may be do some other manipulations
                return response.data;
            else
                // reject with error
                return $q.reject('some error occured');
        })
        .catch(function(reason){
            if(retriesCount++ < 3)
                // some error, let me try to recover myself once again
                return doWork();
            else
                // mission failed... finally reject
                return $q.reject(reason);
        });
}


doWork().then(console.log, console.error);
```

Comment: Note: you can use `.catch(function(){})` instead of `.then(null, function(){})`

Comment: I upvoted but I agree with @Dinistro, you NEED to you proper syntax here and catch the promise rejection in the .catch method. This is theeeee way to deal with rejected promises.

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but as I am here;

I prefer to use the `$http` error for its native error handling, rather than returning a success via a `200` and an error status in the response.

printing `400` or `500` errors in the console is not an issue, if you are debugging you see them if not you don't.

```
angular.module('workModule', [])

// work provider handles all api calls to get work
.service('workProvider', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

    var endpoint = '/api/v1/work/';

    this.Get = function(){
        // return the promise, and use 404, 500, etc for errors on the server
        return $http.get(endpoint);
    };

}])

.controller('workController', ['workProvider', function('workProvider'){

    workProvider.Get().then(
        function(response){ // success
            console.log(response.data);
        },
        function(response){ // error
             console.log(response.data);           
        }
    )

}])
```

Comment: agreed - the server should only return 200 if the operation was successful. this has an impact on system monitoring and logging (errors masked in 200 responses). the exception to this would be data validation (200 is ok to return to the client if its a valid user flow to send incorrect data with a response on how to fix).

Comment: I have the following in the service:  
 `return $http.get(endpoint).then(function(response) { return response.data; }, function(error) {  return error.data; })`


but when an error happens, data is passed to successCallback (first function in then() ) instead of errorCallback (second function in then() ).

I've tried returning $q.reject(error.data) instead of returning error.data, but doesn't works.

Why is this happening?

Comment: @AlejandroSanzDíaz where does the "Error" happen? is this a response? If so what is the response code of your "Error". 200 = success, 4XX or 5XX will result in error. Also check the docs for [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#) try not using `then` and rather `success` and `error` callbacks. i'll edit if this is the case.

Comment: I finally solved it using `return $q.reject(error.data);` inside errorCallback function. :) Thanks anyway.