# Angular resolves the promise returned by "then" function when the main promise is rejected

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

Can someone explain why the second promise returned by then function is resolved? It looks like Angular JS bug in its Promises implementation. According to the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) the second promise should also have been rejected.

```js
// Code goes here
var myMod = angular.module("myMod", []);
myMod.controller('bodyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.promise.then(function(d) {
      console.log("success called");
      return d;
    }, function(d) {
      console.log("failure called");
      return d;
    })
    .then(function(d) {
      console.log("success called2");
      return d;
    }, function(d) {
      console.log("failure called2");
      return d;
    });
    
    $timeout(function() {
      deferred.reject();
    }, 2 * 1000);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myMod">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="bodyCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758058/angularjs-promise-rejection-chaining

Comment: @georgeawg ...or return `$q.reject()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *@Nikolaj Dam Larsen* and *@georgeawg* says, your problem is that in your errorCallback() you aren't throwing the exception. See the following example ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/KdYRU9Qqj4hnmKdYnvas?p=preview))...

```
function bodyCtrl($timeout, $q){
    deferred.promise
    .then(function(d) { //Promise 1
        console.log("success called");
        return d;
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("failure called");
        throw e; //Throw instead return
    })
    .then(function(d) { //Promise 2
        console.log("success called2");
        return d;
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("failure called2");
        throw e; //Throw instead return
    });

    $timeout(function() {
        deferred.reject("Custom Rejected: " + new Date());
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Also check this post to understand better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559341/using-success-error-finally-catch-with-promises-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. It occurs because by providing the promise with an errorCallback, you're actually handling/resolving/catching the rejection (just as if you were catching an exception in a try...catch block). If you remove the first errorCallback function, you should be seeing `failure called2` in the developer console instead, or if you in the first callback throw a new exception.